# Any continuous function is Baire function?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

A have doubt.

Afirmation. All continuous function is Baire function.

Let $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ continuous function. X compact hausdorff with $\mathcal{B}\ \sigma$-algebra of Baire.
Let $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} O_n\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ compact set. (sigma-algebra of Baire in $\mathbb{R}$)
Now, $f^{-1}(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} O_n)=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}f^{-1}(O_n)$ compact set, and $f^{-1}(O_n)$ open sets. Therefore, $f^{-1}(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} O_n)\in \mathcal{B}(X)$. Therefore $f$ is Baire function.

It is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Baire-$\sigma$-algebra is generated by closed $G_\delta$-sets. If $\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty O_i$ is closed with open $O_n$, then also $f^{-1}(\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty O_i)$ is closed. Moreover $f^{-1}(\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty O_i) = \bigcap_{i=1}^\infty f^{-1}(O_i)$. Again using the continuity we see that $f^{-1}(O_i)$ is open. Thus $f^{-1}(\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty O_i)$ is Baire-measurable.

Since we only need to prove measurability on a generating set-system, we get that $f$ is measurable according to the Baire-$\sigma$-algebras.